# gae security - is hacking app engine application as hard as hacking google?

Tags: security, google-app-engine

I have been suffered from hackers and malware attacks. I want to know if I change my host to app engine does it mean I will get same security as google website? Its obvious that google account associated with it might be hacked but I mean in other cases.

Comment: Maybe security.stackexchange.com might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Why AppEngine : The Reliability, Performance, and Security of Google's Infrastructure](https://developers.google.com/appengine/whyappengine#reliable) says

> The same security, privacy and data protection policies we have for Google's applications applies to all App Engine applications. We take security very seriously and have measures in place to protect your code and application data.

Whether that will improve your situation depends on the source of your troubles.  Changing your hosting service will not remedy flaws in your application that allow abuse of authority.

Comment: I did already read this. but it says same policies. I dont know if it means exact same security.

Comment: yes I meant only hosting security. not application flaws and database flaws and etc.

Comment: @rah, There have been a few [successful breaches](http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/06/02/us-google-hacking-idUSTRE7506U320110602) of Google's perimeter but I don't think there's enough publicly available data to compare the security track record of GAE (a single product that's been on the market for a few years) to the security track record of Google's network which has been a high profile target for ~15 years.  The best you can do is find out whether the same personnel have been reviewing both, and whether GAE gets the same perimeter defenses and intrusion detection.

Comment: If you have poorly written PHP or (java, python, go) and your using Cloud SQL that has sql injection problems there is little that appengine can do to prevent this.  Some fundamentals of appengine prevent certain types of attacks.  No writing to the filesystem prevents all sorts of vectors.  Using the datastore prevents SQL injection as GQL is not SQL and is read only.  BUt to be confident you need to look at your application, and how well in maps to appengines infrastructure, and what attack vectors are prevented by appengine.

Comment: while i see in cloud sql u can limit authorized application it shouldnt let sql injection either. should it?